# lens vs. lenses

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-naming, faq-suggestion

We currently have [lens](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lens) and [lenses](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lenses) tags. "Lens" seems to be more used, and yesterday I've tried moving ~5 questions from "lenses" to "lens", but "lenses" tags shows up again, and I guess it makes more sense to use it, since some questions deal with lens comparisons and singular does not make sense there. Should I try to move all "lens" to "lenses", or is there some other way to handle this?

Comment: This is becoming an issue again - should we re-tag and if so, which way. `[lens]` is most popular, but opinions are divided. I'm in the `[lenses]` camp.

Comment: Note: tag synomyms are up: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/tag-folksonomy-and-tag-synonyms/ and http://photo.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms

Answer (score 8):

I think it should be [lenses](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lenses) only. Having only one tag keeps all lens related questions together and in my opinion having it plural makes more sense since the questions are after all about lenses, some only about one but together plural.

Comment: I prefer the singular "lens" over the plural "lenses", but choosing one or the other is the really important thing here.

Comment: The reason I like the plural better might well be that English is not my first language and in Icelandic the plural has a more natural feel to it.

Answer (score 5):

This is really a question of singular verses plural tags.

Stackoverflow has [tag synonyms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50088/official-repository-of-tag-synonyms) to link tags that are considered the same.

Perhaps we should just wait a while and see which is naturally more popular? What people tend to tag will also be what people tend to search for...

Comment: In that respect, `[lens]` wins, and also happens to be the most popular tag in use on the site

Answer (score 2):

I guess it depends on what the question is about. If it is a question about a specific single lens, then the [lens](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lens) tag is appropriate. However, if the question has to do with a variety of lenses, the [lenses](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lenses) tag is more appropriate. Despite the fact that they are similar, they are not identical, and have different meanings.

Comment: I think we should put something about this in the FAQ, or somewhere on the site.  To make it clear.

Comment: Disagree, too much specialization. Whether I'm searching for information on a particular lens or I'm trying to find something about lenses, 'lenses' seems fine to me.

Comment: @gabr: I would be fine with one tag, as I generally prefer fewer rather than tons. I do see a distinction between these two, however the distinction is rather slim, and they could easily be rolled into one.